Is the word "suddenly" really less used in casual conversation than the phrase “all of a sudden”?
According to Google's historic word count of written English, the word "suddenly" is being at the moment used about 200 times more than the phrase "all of a sudden".
How come then that on TV and on YouTube not many people say “suddenly" I have just heard one person saying it. She was an Asian woman. All other people, who wanted to express the same thing, said "all of a sudden". I think I have heard 10-20 people saying it during my short study of spoken media outlets, conducted during the month of October 2024.
I am guessing that the Asian woman probably learned most her English from books, in contrast to all native English speakers who learned their English from mum and dad, and friends, before they even started school. So, as also suggested by one of my commenters, the phrase “all of a sudden” could be a more informal way of saying “suddenly”, and therefore more likely to be used in casual conversation.
Am I guessing right, or otherwise how do we explain it?

What makes you think this has changed? Where are you seeing this change?

I use both, as far as I remember.

Curiously, evidence from  Goggle Books suggests just the opposite. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+of+a+sudden%2Csuddenly&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true

@Gio. Could it be that "suddenly" is more common in written English than spoken?

Frequency illusion

COCA which contains a lot of informal texts (such as blogs) and is mostly recent has "suddenly" 77730 instances vs "all of a sudden" 12194

It's certainly not the case that all of a sudden is a new expression. People have used both suddenly and all of a sudden for the last 300 years. As to why you might use all of a sudden rather than suddenly, the phrase all of a sudden is more emphatic and more informal. And as to why you've just started noticing it, I don't know. Maybe the TV channels/YouTube videos you watch have gotten more informal lately.

@Peter Shor. Ok, so “all of a sudden” is more emphatic and informal. That, could be the answer why it is more used in spoken English. In written English “suddenly” may be more used because it is more formal. And why it is more used in blogs than “all of a sudden” could be because bloggers like to abbreviate and prefer shorter ways when typing. Like lol, etc.

I wonder whether you're thinking of a particular usage pattern. There are some in which both could be used, like immediately preceding or following a clause ("___, she spoke up" or "She spoke up ____"), but only "suddenly" is usable in the pattern "She ____ spoke up."

Now you've got me wondering what suddens used to be.

Prolly, for the reason that even to that extent most of us are lazy. In any case, unless you're preparing a university thesis why would you mind?
